# Sort by both index and value in Multi-indexed data of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, multi-index

Suppose, I have a dataframe as below:

```
    year    month   message
0   2018    2   txt1
1   2017    4   txt2
2   2019    5   txt3
3   2017    5   txt5
4   2017    5   txt4
5   2020    4   txt3
6   2020    6   txt3
7   2020    6   txt3
8   2020    6   txt4
```

I want to figure out top three number of messages in each year. So, I grouped the data as below:

```
df.groupby(['year','month']).count()
```

which results:

```
            message
year    month   
2017    4   1
        5   2
2018    2   1
2019    5   1
2020    4   1
        6   3
```

The data is in ascending order for both indexes. But how to find the results as shown below where the data is sorted by year (ascending) and count (descending) for top n values. 'month' index will be free.

```
            message
year    month   
2017    5   2
        4   1
2018    2   1
2019    5   1
2020    6   3
        4   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value_counts` gives you sort by default:

```
df.groupby('year')['month'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
year  month
2017  5        2
      4        1
2018  2        1
2019  5        1
2020  6        3
      4        1
Name: month, dtype: int64
```

If you want only 2 top values for each year, do another groupby:

```
(df.groupby('year')['month'].value_counts()
   .groupby('year').head(2)
)
```

Output:

```
year  month
2017  5        2
      4        1
2018  2        1
2019  5        1
2020  6        3
      4        1
Name: month, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i am looking for.

Comment: we can also chain `head` and `value_counts` with apply: `df.groupby('year')['month'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))`

Answer (score 2):

This will sort by year (ascending) and count (descending).

```
df = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).count().sort_values(['year', 'message'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems working. Actually, i have another part, How can i limit my result for top 2 values for each year?

Comment: You can group the df again by 'year' and apply head(n), where n would be the number of rows you want to return for each year.```df = df.groupby('year').head(2)```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort_index`, specifying `ascending=[True,False]` so that only the second level is sorted in descending order:

```
df = df.groupby(['year','month']).count().sort_index(ascending=[True,False])

              message
year month         
2017 5            2
     4            1
2018 2            1
2019 5            1
2020 6            3
     4            1
```

Comment: This won't sort "count" in descending order.

Comment: @YoungWookBa you are right. Unfortunately, Its not working.

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
df.groupby(['year', 'month']).count().sort_values(axis=0, ascending=False, by='message').sort_values(axis=0, ascending=True, by='year')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It seems working. How can i limit my result for say top 2 values for each year?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for it.

```
df.groupby(['year', 'month']).count().sort_index(axis=0, ascending=False).sort_values(by="year", ascending=True)
```

Comment: Tried. Its not sorting 'count' in descending order.